# sentry POST data is not being propagated to the UI

Tags: python, sentry, raven

I’m having an issue with the python sdk for sentry on a server that I’m running. On POST requests the body is being suppressed/not being sent to the sentry UI, and I can’t figure out why.

I’m declaring the client like so:

```
ignore_exceptions = ['HTTPNotFound']
sentry_client = Client(
    SENTRY_DSN,
    ignore_exceptions=ignore_exceptions
)
```

As far as I can tell, to NOT include post data you need to also pass something akin to

```
processors = (
    'raven.processors.RemovePostDataProcessor',
)
```

(I read that in the documentation [here](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/advanced/) under the sanitization section)

I'm definitely not passing that, so I'm confused about why the body isn't showing up anywhere. Is there some sort of default I need to override? Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks so much for any help, and let me know if I can clarify/improve my question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, ultimately figured this out. It wasn't really an issue with sentry itself, it's that I'd been passing an empty value to the `data` object.

I'd been using the logic at the end of [this page](https://github.com/falconry/falcon/issues/266) to send things to sentry. As it happened, `request.params` was empty. I ultimately needed to return `request.stream.read(request.content_length or 0).decode('utf-8')` instead. My understanding is that sentry doesn't use request.params for JSON bodies, but I'm not exactly sure of that.

Hopefully this helps somebody down the road!